# canvas.toDataURL() From a live video feed capture then save to fileserver with reference in DB

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, canvas

I am working on a database where we need to have user form data and an image captured from a web cam then send the user data to the DB with a link to the photo on a file server. I am using the code found here http://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php (with added dataurl and base64 coding) for the image capture to canvas. I have searched for the past 2 weeks (unknown separate pieces of code changes and reversions) prior to posting here and have read a few people stating that a similar question has been asked about the Canvas.toDataURL() but it is just not working for me.

I am getting a file uploaded as a png but the file has a size of 0. I have no experience with other forms of coding (ruby/api/ajax/python) so I am not able to code with those. If those are mandatory then I will have to find another method (action script through Flash possibly) to make this work or abandon this until those scripts are learned.

Any info if this is even possible using PHP and mySQL would be helpful so I am not trying to create something that is not possible. The platofrm/delivery system will be an in house server on our intranet. currently testing on the web host server on windows computers running google chrome (also tested on firefox, opera and IE) Thanks in advance for taking the time to read through.

In my form.php

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
if (canvas.getContext) {
    var C = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

$('#canvas').submit()(function(event) {
// feel free to choose your event ;) 

// just for example
// var OFFSET = $(this).offset();
// var x = event.pageX - OFFSET.left;
// var y = event.pageY - OFFSET.top;

// standard data to url
var imgdata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
// modify the dataUrl so the browser starts downloading it instead of             just showing it
var newdata = imgdata.replace(/^data:image\/png/,'data:application/octet-    stream');
// give the link the values it needs
       $('a.linkwithnewattr').attr('download','your_pic_name.png').attr('href',newdata);

});
```

In my addcontent.php

```
<?php 
include("connectionInfo.php");

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$duedate = $_POST['duedate'];
$employee = $_POST['employee'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$estimate = $_POST['estimate'];
$dataURL = $_POST["canvas"];


    //input file into images folder
$image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $dataURL);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $dataURL);
$image = base64_decode($dataURL);
$filename = "$duedate$name.png";
file_put_contents('images/' . $filename, $dataURL);

    // create path for image upload
$path = "images/" . $filename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$path);

    //show file location
echo "Stored in: ". $path;

    //store file path in database
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO JobBags (image) VALUES ('$path')")){
  echo "Successfull!!";} else {
    echo '---fail-sadface---';}

            // put customer info into job bag database
$sql = "INSERT INTO JobBags (name, phone, duedate, employee, address, email, estimate, image) 
VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$duedate', '$employee', '$address', '$email', '$estimate', '$dataURL')";

    //check if jobbag created correctly
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully.";
    } else {
echo "Error: " . $mysqli . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


// close connection to database
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: at least `'data:application/octet-    stream'`   should be  `'data:application/octet-stream'`

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(imgdata);` ?

Comment: canvas is used as form and probably as canvas element? `.submit()` normally is applied to a `form` tag, not to a canvas. If you want the data to be sent you shoud set it as a value of an form element (`input` for example), not to a link as you are doing `.attr('href',newdata);` ... use hidden input field ... your code is a mess

Comment: Your symptom (png size==0) might indicate a cross-origin security violation has occurred. Your video must be hosted on the same domain as your webpage or else `context.toDataURL` will automatically be disabled (and your png will have size==0).